# Gerrit gives missing change-id error even though the change-id is there

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm trying to push some changes to gerrit but gerrit is giving me back a remote error

```
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (missing Change-Id in commit message )
```

I do have the change-id in the last paragraph just like usual.

```
user type is shown in settings and user switchboard

Change-Id: I6b752abec9cf423d088bae4bfd939079dff21b3d
```

How can I push this change for review?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was trying to push multiple commits (I thought it was only one) to gerrit and some of the commits did not have change-ids amended to the end of the commit message.

gerrit didn't like those commits, so I brought all the commits to one and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is almost a month old now, but it's gone unanswered and I like to have closure.  :-)

Are you *sure* it's in the last paragraph?  No extraneous characters in the commit message, etc?

If you don't need that specific Change-Id, amend the commit and remove that line so the commit-msg hook will regenerate it.